# Problem with URL myweb_war_exploded in intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, url, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate version and Tomcat 9.
I have the URL problem when I start server its run this URL with prefix (`myweb`) which is my project name and (`_war_exploded`).

```
localhost:8080/myweb_war_exploded/
```

Then I make another page for example login when I run below link:

```
localhost:8080/login
```

Its give me below error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Type Status Report
Message JSP file [/login.jsp] not found
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.35
```

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configure-web-app-deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

When you type the url localhost:8080/myweb_war_exploded/ it tries to load either index.html, index.jsp . so try localhost:8080/myweb_war_exploded/login.jsp or below options

1 . You can change the name of login.jsp to index.jsp (OR)

2 . Add new entry login.jsp in conf/web.xml(at the end of the page you will find set of welcome-file tags) --> localhost:8080/myweb_war_exploded/ - now login.jsp will be loaded (provided no index.html or index.jsp is there)

Comment: i want to know why it's adding /myweb_war_exploded/ to my url by default. i need that solution